# How to color cell in excel using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, excel

How to color cells vertically? Example I want to color all data in cell"I" up to the last.

here what I've tried so far:

```
For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            For j = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
                xlSheet.Cells(i + 8, j + 1) =
                ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(j)
                formatRange = xlSheet.Cells(i + 8, j + 1)
                formatRange.BorderAround(Excel.XlLineStyle.xlDash, Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlThin, Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic)
                formatRange = xlSheet.Cells(i + 8, 9 + j)
                formatRange.Interior.Color = system.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(system.Drawing.Color.Red)
            Next
        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this work for you:

```
xlSheet.Range("I:I").Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(system.Drawing.Color.Red)
```

Comment: No, sir. I want all the data in Cell I has a color.

Comment: @Miggs: Which cell? You said cell "I", which doesn't have any meaning in Excel, so I presumed you actually meant column "I".

Comment: Oh man its hard for me to explain in English. can I upload pics in here?

Answer (score 0):

This will do it for you.

```
Sub ColorCol(ColID As String, R As Long, G As Long, B As Long)
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Rr As Range
With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, ColID).End(xlUp).Row
Set Rr = .Range(ColID & "1", ColID & LastRow)
For Each Cell In Rr.Cells
Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(R, G, B)
Next
End With
End Sub
Sub Main()
ColorCol "A", 255, 0, 0
End Sub
```

Calling it from another sub

```
Sub Main()
ColorCol "A",255,0,0
End Sub
```

Nota: Works on your *Active Sheet*